# CFML - Array and Scope - Object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Struct cannot be used as an array

Tags: arrays, variables, scope, coldfusion, cfml

I would like to use scopes for my array variable names.

This example works.

```
<cfset person_first_name[1] = "John">
<cfset person_first_name[2] = "Jack">
<cfset x = ArrayLen(person_first_name)>
```

However, this code occures the following error: "Object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Struct cannot be used as an array"

```
<cfset person.first_name[1] = "John">
<cfset person.first_name[2] = "Jack">
<cfset x = ArrayLen(person.first_name)>
```

Isn't it possible to name the variables like that?

Comment: What version of CF? I recall some instances of CF treating complex variable declatations like that as structures, not arrays.  Explicitly declaring the subkey, person.first_name as an array first got around the issue. I.e. person.first_name = [], then appending values to it, or initializing it in one line like person.first_name = ["John","Jack"]

Comment: I use CF2018. The declaration works, the error doesnt occure anymore. Thanks for that hint. There are a lot more variables like id, last_name or dob. I get the data from a query and fill the array during the loop.

Comment: Not sure what the code is doing, but might consider leaving it as a query or using an array of structures instead, which is a lot more intuitive imo :) Like personArray[1] = { first_name = "...", dob = "..."}, etc...

Comment: My intention is to separate data processing and output from each other and to make my code, file and directory structure cleaner and more comprehensible. I prefer the spelling with a dot. On the left is the type of data and on the right of the dot what information it is. The arrays are filled in a loop over the query result. For output, I loop over the array and access the individual data via the index: <cfloop array="#person.id#" index="i">#person.id[i]# #person.first_name[i]#  #person.last_name[i]#<br></cfloop>.

Comment: And there is another aspect. To generate less code I would like to use the same code or the same functions for selecting and outputting a single data record (e.g. for a form) or for a list. A single data record is then an array with only one element.

Comment: Based on the comments so far, I think you can achieve all your objectives regarding simplicity and such by simply outputting the query results.

Comment: Not if further data processing takes place in the query loop. E.g. the calculation of the age of a person based on the date of birth. I don't want this code in the output file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a declaration for the array solved the problem. Thanks @SOS.

```
<cfset person.first_name = []>
```